# Pandas: How to list out the numbers between starting and ending values, present within a column, using another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe that contains values corresponding to a column setting -

```
import pandas as pd

data_0 = {'setting':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
        'values': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0,1,2,3, 5,6]
        }

df_0 = pd.DataFrame(data_0)
```

I have another dataframe that contains relevant starting and ending values for each  setting -

```
data_1 = {'setting':[0,1,2,2],
        'start_value': [1,0,1,3],
        'end_value':[3,2,3,6]
        }
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
```

Now, I'd like to extract the values from df_0 based on start_value and end_value from df_1.

The final output should look like this -

```
data_2 = {'setting':[0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        'start_value': [1,1,0,0,1,1,3,3],
        'end_value':[3,3,2,2,3,3,6,6],
        'values_from_data_0':[1,2,0,1,1,2,3,5]
        }
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
```

```
   setting  start_value  end_value  values_from_data_0
0        0            1          3                   1
1        0            1          3                   2
2        1            0          2                   0
3        1            0          2                   1
4        2            1          3                   1
5        2            1          3                   2
6        2            3          6                   3
7        2            3          6                   5
```

Please note the missing value 4 corresponding to column `setting = 2`.

Here's my naive (and wrong) attempt -

```
import numpy as np
list_final = []
for index, row in df_1.iterrows():

    value_start = row['start_value']
    value_end = row['end_value']
    assert value_start<value_end

    values = np.arange(value_start, value_end)
    list_final.append(values)

df_1["values_from_data_0"] = list_final
df_1 = df_1.explode('values_from_data_0')

print(df_1)
```

This is almost right. However, since it doesn't take the values from `df_0` and instead uses `arange`, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the intervals within a setting are non-overlapping, you need to use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
out = (pd.merge_asof(df_0.reset_index().sort_values(by='values'),
                     df_1.sort_values(by='start_value'),
                     by='setting', left_on='values', right_on='start_value')
         .query('values < end_value')
         .set_index('index').sort_index()
         .rename(columns={'values': 'values_from_data_0'})
      )
```

Or, using [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor)'s [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

out = (df_0.conditional_join(df_1, 
                             ('setting', 'setting', '=='),
                             ('values', 'start_value', '>='),
                             ('values', 'end_value', '<'),
                             df_columns = {'values': 'values_from_data_0'}
                            )
      )
```

Output:

```
   values_from_data_0  setting  start_value  end_value
0                   1        0            1          3
1                   2        0            1          3
2                   0        1            0          2
3                   1        1            0          2
4                   1        2            1          3
5                   2        2            1          3
6                   3        2            3          6
7                   5        2            3          6
```

Comment: I was about to deliver the janitor approach but you were faster with your update ;)

Comment: minor edit to your solution @mozway

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
tmp = df_0.merge(df_1, how='left')
cond1 = tmp['values'] >= tmp['start_value']
cond2 = tmp['values'] < tmp['end_value']
out = tmp[cond1 & cond2].reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:, [0, 2, 3, 1]]\
                        .rename({'values':'values_from_data_0'}, axis=1)
```

out:

```
    setting start_value end_value   values_from_data_0
0   0       1           3           1
1   0       1           3           2
2   1       0           2           0
3   1       0           2           1
4   2       1           3           1
5   2       1           3           2
6   2       3           6           3
7   2       3           6           5
```

Comment: This approach is inefficient if you have many items in each group, you'll create all combinations to filter only a few relevant ones.

Answer (score 1):

Following your [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) approach, you can use this one :

```
aggvals = df_0.groupby("setting")["values"].agg(list)

out = (df_1.assign(values_from_data_0=[
        [i for i in lst if s<=i<e] for s,e,lst in zip(
         df_1["start_value"], df_1["end_value"], df_1["setting"].map(aggvals))])
     .explode("values_from_data_0", ignore_index=True))

# 1.1 ms ± 14.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loopseach)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   setting  start_value  end_value values_from_data_0
0        0            1          3                  1
1        0            1          3                  2
2        1            0          2                  0
3        1            0          2                  1
4        2            1          3                  1
5        2            1          3                  2
6        2            3          6                  3
7        2            3          6                  5
```